# Mac Terminal change PDF author

Tags: macos, pdf, terminal

I need to change the author of a PDF file on my Mac. I have tried to use grep and sed to accomplish this, but haven't succeeded.

If I open a PDF file in Preview.app and go to Tools > Show Inspector I see "Author: yonatan".

Is it possible to use Terminal.app to change this string?

Thanks

P.S. I know I can create a new User Account on my Mac or use Adobe Acrobat Professional.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use Automator. I dont think that sed is going to work because pdfs are largely binary, or very jumbled at the least. One of the defined 'pdf' actions in Automator is defining metadata, one field which is author. Then call the automator workflow with terminal, or just save the workflow as a droplet.

Comment: that was awesome thank you! I have never used Automator and didn't know it had exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 20):

1. open *Automator* & create a *New Workflow*
2. search *"spec*" & add ***Get Specified Finder Items***
3. search *"meta"* & add ***Set PDF Metadata***
4. drag-drop the desired PDFs onto the *Get Specified Finder Items* area
5. in the *Set PDF Metadata* area, update the metadata
6. in the upper-right corner, click ***[Run]***

For more detail see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: i didn't know this existed. screenshot is super helpful

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one upvote! This is the first time I have found a valid use case for Automator. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

A better way would be to make use of [`exiftool`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool), which on Mac you could install with use of [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install exiftool
```

You would then edit your metadata in your PDF in the following manner:

```
exiftool  -Title="Change This Title" -Subject="Fun and PDF" change_my_meta.pdf
```

### Removing metadata

If you only want to remove metadata you can use [`pdf-redact-tools`](https://github.com/firstlookmedia/pdf-redact-tools):

```
pdf-redact-tools --sanitize untrusted.pdf
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `exiftool` does **NOT** remove the metadata - it simply appends a bloc saying "here's the new metadata". The old information is still there.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to pdf-react-tools! The project is not maintainted anymore, and now suggests to use [dangerzone](https://github.com/firstlookmedia/dangerzone) instead

Answer (score 3):

Having used the proposed methods, I obtained a decrease in quality of my paper (using pdf-redact-tools).
For me, using MacOS, the best way to irreversibly remove all metadata from a pdf was performed using both exiftool and qpdf, as follows.

1. replace metadata with nulls

```
exiftool -all:all= CLEAN_file.pdf -overwrite_original
```

2. linearize the pdf to remove the old metadata (which were replaced with nulls), preventing from restoring of these metadata:

```
qpdf --linearize file_from_exif.pdf file_out.pdf
```